# How to use (get and set) user data with Azure Data Storage and MS Bot Framework?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, botframework

I'm using Azure Storage in a MS Bot Framework project.
I've read about the configuration of the service within the bot in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state-azure-table-storage) and I have already applied this to my project correctly. I know that there were these primitives for accessing and use conversation/user/... data (described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state)). The problem is that the methods described in this last page are all obsolete and useless. I was wondering if there is a way to use these old methods also with the azure storage or there are similar method to use it or I'm forced to use the original Azure storage methods to access this data (like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-dotnet)), since in the MS documentation I've found only how to configure the storage and not how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 `databags` you can use to store state data.  They live within the `context` object.  They are `UserData`, `ConversationData`, and `PrivateConversationData`

As far as how to access them (get/set), this depends on where you are trying to get to the data from.  If you are in the messages controller (no access to context object) you would have to do something like this:

```
var message = activity as IMessageActivity;
using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, message))
{
    var botDataStore = scope.Resolve<IBotDataStore<BotData>>();
    var key = Address.FromActivity(message);

    ConversationReference r = new ConversationReference();
    var userData = await botDataStore.LoadAsync(key, BotStoreType.BotUserData, CancellationToken.None);

    //set state data
    userData.SetProperty("key 1", "value1");
    userData.SetProperty("key 2", "value2");
    //get state data
    userData.GetProperty<string>("key 1");
    userData.GetProperty<string>("key 2");

    await botDataStore.SaveAsync(key, BotStoreType.BotUserData, userData, CancellationToken.None);
    await botDataStore.FlushAsync(key, CancellationToken.None);
}
```

In a dialog or when you do have access to the context object it's as simple as

```
context.UserData.SetValue("KEY ONE", "value1");
context.UserData.GetValue<string>("KEY ONE");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! @JasonSowers Am I forced to use the method SaveAsync to save the data in the botDataStore or is it automatic? Besides, there is no way to access the user data without context and an activity?

Comment: you have to use save async when outside of a dialog

Comment: Ok thanks.. And is there a way to access UserData without using a context or an activity?

Comment: You could access it directly from your azure table if you needed to, but as far as programmatically you would not be able to access it without the context and the activity